# Python's "from some_module import *" in Lua

Tags: module, lua

In Python, I can write `from my_module import *` and all of the members of `my_module` will be available in the local scope. e.g.

My module definition:

```
my_module = {}
my_module.a = 1
my_module.b = 2
```

Use in another file:

```
from my_module import *
return a + b
#=> 3
```

Can I do this in Lua? How?

Comment: `local my_module = require("my_module"); local a, b = my_module.a, my_module.b; return a+b`

Comment: That would be more like `from my_module import a, b`. What if there are (extreme example) 500 things I'm importing? I'd rather not manually import all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those value in the local scope, your only choice is to actually mame them:

```
--in main.lua
local mymodule = require("mymodule")
local a, b = mymodule.a, mymodule.b

--in mymodule.lua
return {a = 1, b = 2}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
--in main.lua
local a, b = table.unpack(require("mymodule"))

--in mymodule.lua
return {1, 2}
```

If you don't want to actually name them, instead, the only way is putting them in the global scope. Here are two examples:

```
--Python's from mymodule import *
--in main.lua
require("mymodule")
print(a + b)

--in mymodule.lua
a, b = 1, 2


--Python's import mymodule
--in main.lua
require("mymodule")
print(mymodule.a + mymodule.b)

--in mymodule.lua
mymodule = {a = 1, b = 2}
```

These are all valid ways, but the most used and safe is the first.

Another possibility is try changing the environment modifying the `_ENV` value:

```
--Python's from mymodule import *
--in main.lua
local _ENV = require("mymodule")

--in mymodule.lua
return {a = 1, b = 2}
```

But then, by changing the environment, you wouldn't have access to all the variables in the global scope (unless you pre-declare them as locals (`local print = print; _ENV = require("mymodule"); print(a);`) or you copy all the variables from the `_G` table to the table returned from `mymodule`), which usually isn't an happy thing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't totally achievable because modifying `local` values (`debug.setlocal` can't define *new* locals) is imperfect. The best bet is to adjust your *environment*, since polluting the global scope is not a great idea, but this isn't non-trivial.

This can actually be accomplished *somewhat* elegantly, if done carefully. I say somewhat, because there will always be the caveat that you must adjust your environment manually for whatever function/chunk you are in. In Lua 5.2+, `local _ENV = ...` is required. In Lua 5.1, `setfenv(1, ...)` will do the trick, and is arguably easier on the eyes.

Here's what we can do. We start by defining a function that returns a cloned environment. `clone` being a shallow table copying function.

```
return function (env)
    env = clone(env or _G)

    return env
end
```

Next, we add our custom `import` function that modifies our new environment directly, instead of returning anything (like `require` does). You can get good and complicated here, implementing different ways to decide what to import into the environment, and how. ('*', for example)

```
-- @module: import.lua
return function (env)
    env = clone(env or _G)

    function env.import (modname, ...)
        local args = { ... }
        local m = require(modname)

        for _, name in next, args
            env[name] = m[name]
        end
    end

    return env
end
```

Which we can use as:

```
local _ENV = require('import')()
-- setfenv(1, require('import')())

import('module_name', 'a', 'b')

return a + b
```

On a small scale this is a fair amount of overhead, just to avoid:

```
local module_name = require('module_name')
local a, b = module_name.a, module_name.b
```

It may prove more useful in a larger document, with many imports. Imports are usually clustered at the top of a document any way, so the extra noise isn't so bad. If you can set `env` as a global value somewhere, it looks a bit cleaner.

```
local _ENV = env()

import('webserver', 'open', 'status', 'close')
import('database', 'connect', 'query', 'disconnect')
import('json', 'parse', 'stringify')
...
```

And could also be used to create sandboxes, assuming care is taken with rewriting the `import` function to not use `require`!

```
local my_env = env { print = print }
my_env.import('my_mod', 'foo', 'bar')

local chunk = loadfile('my_file.lua', 'bt', my_env)
```